# Drupal hook_file_insert issue

Tags: drupal-7

I'm working with the [hook_file_insert function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_insert/7) and keep running into the same issue over and over again.

Let's take a look at the code:

```
function mymodule_file_insert($file) {

    $src = $file->source // the file field a.k.a field_upload_und_0
    file_save_upload($src, array(), 'public://styles/'); // <-- Here's where the issue is.
    $file->description = 'Change desc value';
    dsm($file) // debug
}
```

So basically when i upload a file i get this error:

The file MyDocument.doc could not be saved. An unknown error has occurred.

Other than that, I'm also trying to change the description value when the file is uploaded/saved. But that's not happening either. It does however, show as changed in the array when i look in the dsm results.

Am i misunderstanding this function? I suppose it only changes the files array and hangs on to. My thinking originally was that it modifies the actual field values but that doesn't seem to be the case.

How could i grab these values and pass them along in my hook_form_submit function? Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution was to pass the $file variable by reference

function mymodule_file_insert(&$file) {...